# Multiple outputs using math.random function

Tags: javascript

So I'm use this code to send a message which randomises the emotes sent in chat (Discord) but I want to make it so when the emotes are sent each emote is different. For example if the user was to send the command it would send: 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3 etc. How would I be able to make it so that each emote is different. The only way I found was making each emote a different var math.random function. Is this any other way because making a different var is kinda long.

```
const randomemote = [
  `:four:`,
  `:one:`,
  `:two:`,
  `:three:`
];
var emotes = randomemote[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomemote.length)];
message.channel.send(`
  ${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}
  ${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}
  ${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}
  ${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}
  ${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}${emotes}
  `)
```

Comment: Make it a function instead, so that the randomize code is hit with each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function which, given the number of times to repeat, makes a random emote that many times.

```js
const randomemote = [
  `:four:`,
  `:one:`,
  `:two:`,
  `:three:`
];
const randEmote = () => randomemote[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomemote.length)];
const multRandEmotes = count => Array.from({ length: count }, randEmote)
  .join('');
const strToSend = `
  ${multRandEmotes(5)}
  ${multRandEmotes(5)}
  ${multRandEmotes(5)}
  ${multRandEmotes(5)}
  ${multRandEmotes(5)}
  `;
console.log(strToSend);
```

You could also make *another* function that, given the number of lines to print and the number of emotes for each line, calls `multRandEmotes` that many times:

```js
const randomemote = [
  `:four:`,
  `:one:`,
  `:two:`,
  `:three:`
];
const randEmote = () => randomemote[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomemote.length)];
const multRandEmotes = count => Array.from({ length: count }, randEmote)
  .join('');
const multiLineEmotes = (lines, count) => `
  ${
    Array.from({ length: lines }, () => multRandEmotes(count))
    .join('\n  ')}
  `;
console.log(multiLineEmotes(5, 5));
console.log(multiLineEmotes(2, 7));
```